# Crash on updating app but not on fresh install

Tags: ios

I've had reports that when users have been trying to update an app I have in the app store the app tries to open with the new version but then crashes. This repeats until the user deletes the app off their phone and does a fresh install.  I've gotten ahold of one of the crash logs but the back trace gives me little to go on.

Shouldn't an update be like a fresh install of the app? How can an update cause a crash but a fresh install not? There should be no residual data from a previous version that could cause a crash.

I've seen another with a similar issue: [iOS crash log, backtrace not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957605/ios-crash-log-backtrace-not-available)

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x2e878efe _exceptionPreprocess + 126  
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3900dce2 objc_exception_throw + 34  
2   Application                    0x0016bd6e 0xda000 + 597358  
3   Application                         0x0016ba16 0xda000 + 596502  
4   Application                         0x0019df38 0xda000 + 802616  
5   Application                         0x0019ddf8 0xda000 + 802296  
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x394f6d3a _dispatch_client_callout + 18  
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x394f796a dispatch_once_f + 42  
8   Application                         0x0019ddb6 0xda000 + 802230  
9   Application                         0x00199478 0xda000 + 783480  
10  Application                         0x0015cb38 0xda000 + 535352  
11  Application                         0x0015b70a 0xda000 + 530186  
12  UIKit                           0x31117cbc -[UIApplication   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272  
13  UIKit                           0x3111760e -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1606  
14  UIKit                           0x31111cc4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 716  
15  UIKit                           0x310adc92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3546  
16  UIKit                           0x310acdf4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68  
17  UIKit                           0x31111400 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612  
18  GraphicsServices                0x3371ab50 _PurpleEventCallback + 604  
19  GraphicsServices                0x3371a73a PurpleEventCallback + 30  
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2e84383a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30  
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2e8437d6 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342  
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2e841fa2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1402  
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2e7ac7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520  
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2e7ac586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102  
25  UIKit                           0x31110626 -[UIApplication _run] + 758  
26  UIKit                           0x3110b88c UIApplicationMain + 1132  
27  Application                         0x0013ecba 0xda000 + 412858  
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x3950bab2 tlv_initializer + 2  


Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395c21f0 _pthread_kill + 8  
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3962a7b2 pthread_kill + 54  
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39572ff4 abort + 72  
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389c198a abort_message + 70  
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389da6e2 default_terminate_handler() + 250  
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3900df7a _objc_terminate() + 190  
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389d81b0 std::_terminate(void (*)()) + 76  
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x389d7a04 _cxa_throw + 112  
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3900ddb6 objc_exception_throw + 246  
9   Application                         0x0016bd6e 0xda000 + 597358  
10  Application                         0x0016ba16 0xda000 + 596502  
11  Application                         0x0019df38 0xda000 + 802616  
12  Application                         0x0019ddf8 0xda000 + 802296  
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x394f6d3c _dispatch_client_callout + 20  
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x394f796a dispatch_once_f + 42  
15  Application                         0x0019ddb6 0xda000 + 802230  
16  Application                         0x00199478 0xda000 + 783480  
17  Application                         0x0015cb38 0xda000 + 535352  
18  Application                         0x0015b70a 0xda000 + 530186  
19  UIKit                           0x31117cbc -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272  
20  UIKit                           0x3111760e -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1606  
21  UIKit                           0x31111cc4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 716  
22  UIKit                           0x310adc92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3546  
23  UIKit                           0x310acdf4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68  
24  UIKit                           0x31111400 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612  
25  GraphicsServices                0x3371ab52 _PurpleEventCallback + 606  
26  GraphicsServices                0x3371a73a PurpleEventCallback + 30  
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2e84383c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32  
28  CoreFoundation                  0x2e8437d6 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342  
29  CoreFoundation                  0x2e841fa2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1402  
30  CoreFoundation                  0x2e7ac7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520  
31  CoreFoundation                  0x2e7ac586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102  
32  UIKit                           0x31110626 -[UIApplication _run] + 758  
33  UIKit                           0x3110b88c UIApplicationMain + 1132  
34  Application                         0x0013ecba 0xda000 + 412858  
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x3950bab4 start + 0
```

Comment: by any chance are you using CoreData and have you changed the model? Also add any info of crash logs, otherwise how should any one be able to help you?

Comment: 1) Yes, there is CoreData and yes, the model was changed. But how can I prevent that crash from happening on the update?   2) I'll edit my question to involve the crash log

Comment: “There should be no residual data from a previous version”—this is totally untrue! All of the user’s data, including their `NSUserDefaults` and whatever you put in the Documents directory, is preserved from one version to another.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done Core Data Migration?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: Ha! That's it. I'm on version 8 of my core data model and had made a small change on it without migrating. I was under the assumption that an update would be like a fresh install.  Thanks Solomiya, I shouldn've thought of that. Moral of the story: Never assume :)